# Mature Branch Strategy On TFS

Tags: branch

My team are finally moving from SourceSafe to TFS 2010, and we are trying to work out our strategy.

We need to be able to put bug fixes into the next service release whilst still working on the current service release. Basically, at some point we will stop bug fixing going in the current release (except a few critical ones) and pilot that release for a week or two. During this time we still want to be fixing bugs so we put them into the next service release. This is separate from the development that will be going into the next major release.

We like the look of the mature branching strategy that involves having a service release branch off of main, a hot fix branch off of service release, and a release branch off of hot fix. What we would then do is have the release branch as the one that we are piloting and still be able to add bug fixes to the service release branch. Then when we finish with the pilot and have made the last critical changes we merge the release branch back into main, via the hot fix and service release branches, and then create a new hot fix and release branch from the service release branch, which will be our next service release.

The big problem I have with this is that I want anything that goes into main to be fully tested. The release branch will be but as we merge it back into main it will pick up any changes that we have checked into the hot fix and service release branches. These changes will not have been tested at this point.

To get around this we are planning on making the devs shelve their changes in the service release branch until after the release has been merged into main. This doesn't seem like the best idea to me, but I can't think of anything else to do to handle this.

Has anyone else had to do something similar and have a better way of handling this?

Comment: You could switch to `Gated Checkins` on your main branch to make sure that all code compiles and all automatic testcases run. It would alleviate the developers from having to manually create a shelveset while keeping your main branch *(automatic)* tested.

Comment: That would be good, however, most of our code is still VB6 and has no automated tests. The best we could do is check to see if it compiles, before merging into main.